# cshell: How do I produce a list of decimal numbers?

Tags: loops, floating-point, csh, tcsh

I want to produce a list of numbers from 1 to 5 incrementing by 0.25 at each step, like this:

```
1.0, 1.25, 1.5, ..., 4.5, 4.75, 5.0
```

Is this possible to do in csh? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `seq` command as:

```
seq 1 0.25 5
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/5abdh)

To display all the numbers in one line you can use the `-s`(separator) option of `seq` as:

```
seq -s' ' 1 0.25 5
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/iGXFV)

Comment: Cheers, how do I display those numbers in one line?